# Why is my H2 database 7x larger on disk than it should be?

Tags: h2

I have an H2 database that has ballooned to several Gigabytes in size, causing all sorts of operational problems. The database size didn't seem right. So I took one little slice of it, just one table, to try to figure out what's going on.

I brought this table into a test environment:

[image]

The columns add up to 80 bytes per row, per my calculations.

The table has 280,000 rows.

For this test, all indexes were removed.

The table should occupy approximately

```
80 bytes per row * 280,000 rows = 22.4 MB on disk.
```

However, it is physically taking up **157 MB**.

I would expect to see some overhead here and there, but why is this database a full 7x larger than can be reasonably estimated?

*UPDATE*

Output from `CALL DISK_SPACE_USED`
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting `MV_STORE=FALSE` on database creation solves the problem. Whole database (not the test slice from the example) is now approximately 10x smaller.

**Update**

I had to revisit this topic recently and had to run a comparison to MySQL. On my test dataset, when MV_STORE=FALSE, the H2 database takes up 360MB of disk space, while the same data on MySQL 5.7 InnoDB with default-ish configurations takes up 432MB. YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

There's always indices, etc. to be taken into account.

Can you try:

`CALL DISK_SPACE_USED('my_table');`

Also, I would also recommend running `SHUTDOWN DEFRAG` and calculating the size again.

Comment: CALL DISK_SPACE_USED() on my table tells me the disk usage is ... zero!? Not sure what's going on here.